# How to add an item to an instance of mutable.DoubleLinkedList[] in Scala?

Tags: scala

```
val list = new mutable.DoubleLinkedList[String]
list.add("foo")
```

This obviously cannot be compiled. How to fix this?

I spent some time with scaladoc, but it seems like the information on how to add an item to a list is a secret. Yes I am relatively new to scala and by the way I am completely frustrated with "syntax sugar" like `:+`, `++` and `:::`. It improves neither readability nor writability.

Comment: Technically `:+`, `++` and `:::` are not syntactic sugar. `:::` is motivated for performance reasons and `:+` is priceless in match statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DoubleLinkedList` is deprecated, use `ArrayBuffer`.

```
val list = new scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[String]
list += "foo"
```